# angular 404 does not work with otherwise templateUrl nor redirectTo

Tags: javascript, angular

trying to add a simple 404.html template but for some reason it does not get rendered. in my app.routes.js I tried the following

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/index.html',
    controller: 'IndexCtrl'
}).otherwise({
    templateUrl: '/templates/404.html'
})
```

I also tried to use redirectTo as below but it does not work

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/templates/404.html'
})
```

when I try to type something like http://localhost:5000/aaaaaaaaaaaaa in console I see 404 response but template is not rendered. do I need to adjust controller ?

Comment: `redirectTo` needs a valid previously defined route path , not a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an specific route for 404 with an specific view `/templates/404.html`.

Than, in the `otherwise()` method call, you can redirect to that route `/404`:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
      controller: 'IndexCtrl'
    })
    .when('/404', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/404.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/404'
    });
});
```

Comment: just tried this but it still does not work, all other pages work normally

Comment: i copied your code and nothing happens...it points to the right template but for some reason it does not work.while in console I see 404

Comment: also if I try to use 404.html instead of index.html for / it works

Comment: If works as you set, than the code posted in the solution works ;)

Comment: do I need to add controller for it ?

Comment: If you need to have some logic yes.. but is not required

Comment: no I dont need any logic I just need it to render but it wont for some reason

Comment: simply nothing gets rendered